# Nginx, SPA & Sphinx Doco Authentication

Tags: django, nginx, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I have an SPA app which uses Azure AD for authentication. It's working well and now I've added some user doco using Sphinx.

I've configured Nginx so the doco is available via `/app/doco`. This works well, however now I would like to also secure it so only Azure AD authenticated users can access the doco. To do this I have made use of the `auth_request` (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module. This works if I am using standard Django authentication but when I use Azure AD authentication it isn't working as the request does not have the users token included etc.

The way I understand the `auth_request` module to work is:

1. User attempts to access `/app/doco`  (which includes the users token)
2. Nginx is configured to check if the user is authenticated by going to `/app/auth_check` (custom Django view) which returns either 200 or 404
3. If 200, user is given access to /app/doco

It feels like that above approach is flawed, trying to hit a square peg through a round hole? Will something like the above work or is there another tool/approach that better fits?

Answer (score 2):

From the Azure side I can't really speak to this since we do not have official documentation for this, but based off of what I have seen on Nginx you should be able to use JWTs and conditional access to achieve this.

Looks like you may need to add JWT validation to your NGINX configuration:

```
auth_jwt "Closed site";
auth_jwt_key_file /etc/nginx/azure.jwk;
```

[image]

Have you seen [this guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/conditional-access-control-with-microsoft-azure-active-directory/) already?

Comment: Yep, I have seen that Nginx Plus includes the ability but unfortunately that is not an option (for me). It is definitely the simplest way I think, aside from the cost.